# Ruby on Rails: ActiveRecord-like queries on non-persisted objects?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activemodel

In my project, a large number of POROs are composed from various data sources such as external APIs. The objects looks like:

```
{id: 1, name: 'Peter', age: 8}, {id: 2, name: 'Jack', age: 4}, {id: 3, name: 'Tom', age: 12}
```

I would like to have an ActiveRecord-like interface to query these objects. Such as `Person.where(name: 'Jack')` and `Person.where("age > ?", 5)`

My attempt looks like this:

```
class Query
    def initialize(objs)
      @objs = objs
    end

    def where(name: nil, age: nil)
      result = @objs 
      result = result.select{|x| x.name == name} if name
      result = result.select{|x| x.age == age}   if age
      result
    end
end
```

It works, but I don't think it is a nice solution:

1. What if there are 20 attributes? The `where` method can become very long and error-prone.
2. What about other useful ActiveRecord query? e.g. `find`, `find_by`, `pluck`, `order by` and many others. Even if I can implement them all, how do I "chain" multiple queries?
3. Efficiency: How to optimize the queries like the sql query planner?
4. Most importantly, how do I implement `Person.where("age > ?", 5)` and other flexible queries?

Am I missing anything? I feel like I am re-inventing the wheel.

I've checked ActiveModel but unfortunately it doesn't have a query system.

Are there any gems out there that can help?

Comment: You could probably do a reasonable job duplicating the functionality of `where`, but it would be a Herculean task to recreate the entire ActiveRecord query interface for in-memory objects. That's not a good subject for a StackOverflow question.

Comment: You are right. I don't want to implement the ActiveRecord interface; I'm looking for gems or tools that can do the heavy-lifting for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably do well to use an object mapper, for example one from https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/orm. An example implementation is shown at http://rom-rb.org/learn/repositories/reading-simple-objects/, but that is probably overkill for what you're doing.

[Hashie](https://github.com/intridea/hashie) has support for methods like `deep_find` for single objects and `deep_locate` for collections of objects. `deep_locate` may work for what you're doing, but keep in mind that a Hashie object will take up more memory than a standard hash.

Example code for `deep_locate`:

```
books = [
  {
    title: "Ruby for beginners",
    pages: 120
  },
  {
    title: "CSS for intermediates",
    pages: 80
  },
  {
    title: "Collection of ruby books",
    books: [
      {
        title: "Ruby for the rest of us",
        pages: 576
      }
    ]
  }
]

books.extend(Hashie::Extensions::DeepLocate)

# for ruby 1.9 leave *no* space between the lambda rocket and the braces
# http://ruby-journal.com/becareful-with-space-in-lambda-hash-rocket-syntax-between-ruby-1-dot-9-and-2-dot-0/

books.deep_locate -> (key, value, object) { key == :title && value.include?("Ruby") }
# => [{:title=>"Ruby for beginners", :pages=>120}, {:title=>"Ruby for the rest of us", :pages=>576}]

books.deep_locate -> (key, value, object) { key == :pages && value <= 120 }
# => [{:title=>"Ruby for beginners", :pages=>120}, {:title=>"CSS for intermediates", :pages=>80}]
```